# retrieve value from textbox and pass to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am drawing d3 graphs,the code is working  fine.But to change the no. of input points which in my case are 100,i have to change them equal to that of textbox value.But while doing so,i have to use location.reload(), and using that it lost the selected value.Can anybody help me.
Here is the code:

html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
function update7()
{
var number=document.getElementById("number");
document.getElementById("nd").value=number.options[number.selectedIndex].text;

}
</script>


<style type="text/css">
.axis path,.axis line
{
fill:none;
stroke:black;
shape-rendering:crispEdges;
}

.axis text
{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}
</style> 


<script type="text/javascript">

var w=800;
 var h=600;
var padding=30;

var dataset=new Array();
var currentdate;
var sec;
var x1;
var y1;







for(var i=0;i<100;i++)//here i have to set the value of textbox instead of 100 
{

 currentdate=new Date();
 sec=currentdate.getSeconds();
sec=+sec;
 x1=Math.floor((Math.random()*100*sec)+10);
x1=+x1;

y1=Math.floor((Math.random()*(100+sec)));
y1=+y1;
dataset.push([x1,y1]);
```

}

```
</script>
```

```
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="fps" ></h1>
<form>

Select number of data-points:
<select id="number" onchange="update7()">
<option></option>
<option>100</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>4000</option>
<option>10000</option>
<option>40000</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="nd" size="20" value="10" >

</form>





</body>


</html>
```

src.js

```
window.onload = function () {
//var tb=document.getElementById("nd");
//tb.setAttribute("onchange",function(){init(tb.value);setupFunc();});
```

setupFunc();
    }

```
var svg;
var xScale;
var yScale;
var rscale;
var xAxis;
var yAxis;

var filterStrength = 20;
var frameTime, lastLoop , thisLoop;





function GetFeed(){



 svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).transition().duration(1000).each("start",function()  {d3.select(this).attr("fill","magenta").attr("r",3);}).attr("cx",function(d){return   xScale(d[0]);}).attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d[1]);})  

.each("end",function(){d3.select(this).attr("fill","black").attr("r",2);});


var thisFrameTime = (thisLoop=new Date) - lastLoop;
  frameTime+= (thisFrameTime - frameTime) / filterStrength;
  lastLoop = thisLoop;
 var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
  fpsOut.innerHTML = "Frame rate: "+(1000/frameTime).toFixed(1) + " fps";




}                      

function setupFunc() {

frameTime = 0;

 xScale=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return  d[0];})]).range([padding,w-padding*2]);

 yScale=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return d[1];})]).range([h- padding,padding]);

 rscale=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(dataset,function(d){return   d[1];})]).range([2,5]);

 svg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);

svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).enter().append("circle").attr("cx",function(d){return   xScale(d[0]);}).attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d[1]);}).attr("r",function(d){return   rscale(d[1]);}).append("title").text(function(d){return "x: "+d[0]+" y: "+d[1];});

 xAxis=d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(5);
 yAxis=d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);



svg.append("g").attr("class","X axis").attr("transform","translate(0,"+(h- padding)+")").call(xAxis)

svg.append("g").attr("class","Y      axis").attr("transform","translate("+padding+",0)").call(yAxis);



lastLoop= new Date;  
GetFeed();
setInterval("GetFeed()",7000);


}
```

Comment: Please create jsFiddle testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [localStorage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) or `cookies` to show your `selected data`  like,

```
newValue=number.options[number.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("nd").value=newValue;
localStorage.setItem("newValue", newValue);// to set new value
```

And to get the `newValue` try this,

```
newValue=localStorage.getItem('newValue');
```

Comment: instead of localStorage i have used sessionStorage so that cache gets clear on closing the browser.Thanx a lot